# How to add a Hibernate property that's really a query

Tags: hibernate

We're using Hibernate to load objects that meet certain criteria.  If the user decides to view the details on one of the objects, I want to pull up some additional information about the object.  One of the "attributes" I'd like to show will require a fairly complex SQL query, but evaluates to a simple boolean.

What's the right way to do this with Hibernate?  Is there a way to indicate a property whose value is the result of a SQL query?  If so, is there a way to prevent the query from being invoked until it's needed?

Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complex that query is and what it returns, you can either use a [formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column) or map your "attribute" as a separate entity ([many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)) that will be lazy-loaded.

Comment: do you have an example of the second option?

Comment: I edited my question to note that the query evaluates to a simple boolean.  So, the formula sounds appropriate, but would it be executed for each object that was loaded, even if I never use that field?

Comment: OK, Google answered my question.  Lazy formula is not supported until Hibernate 3.

Comment: Hibernate 3.3.2 is the current version. And lazy formula evaluation is very much supported; however it would require bytecode instrumentation  (like any other non-association property in order to be lazy loaded)

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a named query? In hibernate annotations, you can have an annotation on an entity class which looks like:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "user.someUsers", query = "select u.* from users u where someparam = :someValue...", resultClass = User.class)
```

I'm sure you can do it in hibernate's XML config also but I don't know the syntax offhand. This would not be a mapped property on the object itself, but you could use this query whenever you want to get back that specific piece of information.